# Distribution of Summation of two discrete random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Here, $X$ and $Y$ are two non-negative independent discrete integer-valued random variable and the support set of $k_1$ and $k_2$ are $ \{ 2,3,...,7 \}$ and $   \{ 5,6,...,12 \} $ respectively.

We have the equation (1):

\begin{equation}
P \{ X + Y = n  \} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} P \{ Y = n - i | X = i \} P \{ X = i  \}
\end{equation}

Here $N = X + Y$ Thus we can define the support set from $N$ as:$ K_N = \{  7,8, ....,19  \} $.

Now I want to make a discrete convolution subroutine that you can just plug in any limits and **there wont be any zero product.**

I came up with the below equation, but I am not sure whether it is correct or not.

$$P \{ X + Y = n  \} =  \sum_{i= {y}_{min} }^{{x}_{max}  } \sum_{n={x}_{min}}^{{y}_{max}} P \{ X = n - i | Y = i = i \} P \{ Y = i  \}   $$

Any help? thank u.

Comment: I take it that we know nothing about the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ (apart from the supports), and we do not know whether or not they are independent.

Comment: Note that the support set for the sum is $7$ to $19$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas,, thanks for the correction. i have edited the question as both random variables are independent.

Comment: Do you know the supports will always consist of consecutive integers?

Comment: @MichaelChirico,, yes. the summation can have any product whose result will be $0$.

Comment: Why are you defacing your question? Reverting to previous version (if this happens again, flagging shall be in order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limits for $j$ in Conrado Costa's equation will be $\max(x_{1min},n-x_{2max})$ to $\min(x_{1max},n-x_{2min})$.

Comment: thanks @Jim. I have tested some values with your formula and results are correct. But I would like to ask u: why you choose $max(x_{1min}, n-x_{2max})$ instead of $min(x_{1min}, n-x_{2max})$.  I know this is a silly question. Actually, I also derived those equation but I could not see why I should choose $max(x_{1min}, n-x_{2max})$ instead of $min(x_{1min}, n-x_{2max})$. I think I am missing something very easy trick here. thanks again.

Comment: Here’s a handwaving explanation.  We know that the indices used for x1 must be a subset of x1min…x1max.  As n increases from its smallest value (x1min+x2min) we know that at some point the smallest value of x1 to construct n must also increase.  So using min(x1min,n-x2max) wouldn’t cut it because n-x2max also increases with n and you’d be stuck with x1min at some point for the largest values of n.

Comment: thats the explanation I was looking for. thanks for such big help!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a convolution of randon variables with support on $\Bbb{Z}$

the general formula you got is incorrect, it should be

$$\Bbb{P} (\tilde{x}_1+ \tilde{x}_2 = n) = \sum_{j = -\infty}^{\infty}\Bbb{P} ( \tilde{x}_2 = n-j \vert \tilde{x}_1 = j) \Bbb{P}(\tilde{x}_1 = j) $$